# need help in creating a function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function to calculate the value of mean, sd, IQR, quantile. I have a database name "bf" and I want to calculate these values for col age. below is my code

```
mysummary=function(bf$age) {s1=mean(bf$age) s2=sd(bf$age)
                            s3=quantile(bf$age,probs=c(0.25,0.50,0.75))
                            s4=IQR(bf$age) summary=list(mean=s1,sd=s2,quantile=s3,IQR=s4) 
                            return(summary)}
```

It throws error

> "Error: unexpected '$' in "mysummary=function(bf$"  "

Not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need to create an anonymous parameter named `x` in function definition and pass the value `bg$age` when calling the function.

```
summaryFun=function(x) {
 s1=mean(x) 
 s2=sd(x)
 s3=quantile(x,probs=c(0.25,0.50,0.75))
 s4=IQR(x) 
 summaryDF=list(mean=s1,sd=s2,quantile=s3,IQR=s4)
 return(summaryDF)
 }
ageSummary = summaryFun(x=bf$age)
```

Comment: You can mark this post as resolved by clicking arrow on the left